# Best way to add watchlist feature in android app? Store each item in SQLite database or as an object inside an array?

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

Hi I'm new to programming and I'm learning by trying to copy parts of various apps. [Like in this app(its a screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7wJa.png)

Should I add every item in SQLite table or object inside arraylist? I want to update the price too every 24 hours so what would be the ideal method?

Answer (score 1):

Is your application connected to a server, and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

For most of the use cases, like if you want to have dynamic datasets and want to application to store the data even after the application is restarted, it is better to store in SQLite.

It would really help if you could explain what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: The app won't be connected to a server but it will update data by passing query to the app store api.